# ls -s command, what type of file size

Tags: files, ls

When you type `ls -s`, what size unit does it use to display the file sizes - bits, bytes, megabytes?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It shows the size of the file in blocks. I guess, it is in KBs. If you use `-h` option along with `-s`, like `ls -sh` you could see the size in human readable format. For more info check the **man** page.

Answer (score 3):

The units are KiBs (1024 bytes).

From [`man ls`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/ls.1.html):

```
-s, --size
       print the allocated size of each file, in blocks
```

But how big is a block? From [`info coreutils ls`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/What-information-is-listed.html#What-information-is-listed):

> Normally the disk allocation is printed in units of 1024 bytes, but this can be overridden (see [Block size](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Block-size.html#Block-size)).

It's also worth noting that `ls -s` says symlinks take 0 space, while `ls -l` doesn't. E.g. `ls -l` gives the size of a link to `/` as 1, `/var` as 4, `/home/username` as 14, etc. As well, `ls -ls` adds a disk size column to `ls -l` on the far left, for example:

```
$ ls -ls /bin/sh /bin/dash
152 -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 154072 Feb 17  2016 /bin/dash
  0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      4 Feb 17  2016 /bin/sh -> dash
```

Comment: How does `ls -ls` consider it?

Comment: @antonimmo Great question. `ls -ls` adds a column to `ls -l` which shows the equivalent of `ls -s`. I edited to add.

Answer (score 0):

It shows the file size in blocks more specifically a block is equals to a KiloByte, for example if it shows `64` that means `64 KB`.